# Command line tool that prints all strings between certain matched keywords

Tags: linux, text, command-line, awk, grep

Consider a pair of keywords: a `start-word` and a `stop-word`. Is there any command-line Linux tool similar to `grep` or `awk` that would print all the lines from the text file that are between a `start-word` and a `stop-word`?

For example, a text file:

> header
>   blah-blah
>   blah
>   begin-message
>   message content line 1
>   message content line 2
>   end-message
>   footer
>   blah-blah
>   blah

By specifying the `start-word` to be 'begin-message' and the `stop-word` to be 'end-message' the expected output should be:

> message content line 1
>   message content line 2

EDIT: Start-stop-words may contain special characters that cannot just be entered in `awk` regular expression patterns, like in case of '**** BEGIN MESSAGE ****' start-word.

Comment: Can the start- and stop-words occur multiple times?

Comment: That would be additional convenience, but it's not crucial.

Comment: Can the words appear mid-line and if so what should happen with the rest of the text on each matching line? If the words contain RE metacharacters like `*` should those be treated as literal characters (e.g. the character `*`) or what they represent in an RE (e.g. a repetion of zero or more expressions)?

Comment: Yes, I'd also like to safely treat special characters in start-stop-words, as they may look like '***** BEGIN *****'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '/begin-message/{ P=1; next } /end-message/ {exit} P' new.txt
```

Comment: +1: You can get rid of the `next` by adjusting the sequence. For eg: `awk '/end-message/{exit};p;/begin-message/{p=1}' new.txt`

Comment: How can I safely treat special characters in start-stop words, like '***** BEGIN MESSAGE *****'?

Answer (score 1):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
$ perl -00ne 'print $1 if /begin-message\n(.*)end-message/s' /tmp/file
message content line 1
message content line 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not include START END

```
awk '/START/{f=1;next} /END/{f=0} f'
```

```
awk '/END/{f=0} f; /START/{f=1}'
```

Include START END

```
awk '/START/{f=1} /END/{f=0;print} f'
```

```
awk '/START/{f=1} f; /END/{f=0}'
```

```
awk '/START/,/END/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one with `gnu-sed`:

```
sed -n '
/begin-message/,/end-message/ {
/begin-message/b
/end-message/b
p
}' file
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat file
header
blah-blah
blah
begin-message
message content line 1
message content line 2
end-message
footer
blah-blah
blah
```

```
$ sed -n '
/begin-message/,/end-message/ {
/begin-message/b
/end-message/b
p
}' file
message content line 1
message content line 2
```